# What are some examples of non-commutative $\mathbb{Q}$-monoids and/or $\mathbb{R}$-monoids?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, abstract-algebra, semigroups-and-monoids

**Definition 0.** Let $R$ denote a commutative semiring with $0$ and $1$. By an $R$-monoid, I mean a monoid $M$ equipped with an action $R \times M \rightarrow M$ denoted $r,m \mapsto m^r$, satisfying the following axioms.

1. $m^1 = m$
2. $(m^r)^s = m^{rs}$
3. $m^0 = 1$
4. $m^{r+s} = m^r m^s$

*Remark.* If $R$ is a ring, then every $R$-monoid is a group, because $1 = m^{0} = m^{-1+1} = m^{-1} m.$

**Examples.**

1. An $\mathbb{N}$-monoid is just a monoid.
2. A $\mathbb{Z}$-monoid is just a group.
3. The set $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ can be regarded as an $\mathbb{R}$-monoid (or a $\mathbb{Q}$-monoid, if we wish), where the law of composition is $(p,q) \mapsto pq$ and the action is $x,p \mapsto p^x.$

> **Questions.**
>
> 1. What are some examples of non-commutative $\mathbb{Q}$-monoids and/or $\mathbb{R}$-monoids?
> 2. What is the usual terminology for $R$-monoids?
> 3. Is there any literature surrounding them? References appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

A nice example.  Goes back to Cayley, 1860 [1].

Formal power series of the form
$$
f(x) = x + a_1x^2+a_2x^3+a_3x^4+\cdots
$$
with real coefficients.  Under composition.  Cayley showed how to do "fractional" composites, of real (or even complex) order.  The series need not converge, even if $f$ does.  That's why I said "formal" power series.

**plug:** I did a generalization for transseries [2].

[1] A. Cayey, On some numerical expansions.  *Quarterly Journal of Pure and Applied Mathematics* **3** (1860) 366--369

[2] G. Edgar, Fractional iteration of series and transseries.  *Transactions of the American Mathematical Society* **365** (2013) 5805--5832

Comment: If you restrict to rational coefficients, you get a $\mathbb Q$-monoid. If you work formally subject to $x^n=0$, this example still works, but now it is a finite-dimensional nilpotent Lie group, quite like André's example.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess that an $\mathbb R$-monoid is the same thing (once you put extra smoothness axioms on the $\mathbb R$-action) as a Lie group whose exponential map $\mathfrak g\to G$ is a diffeomorphism. The Heisenberg group
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & * & * \\
0 & 1 & * \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
is the simplest non-commutative example of such a group. Take the same example but restrict $*\in \mathbb Q$ to get an example of a $\mathbb Q$-monoid which is not an $\mathbb R$-monoid.

Comment: For the $\mathbb Q$ version to work it is important that the group to be nilpotent, so that the exponential preserve rational matrices. . . There is a smaller, though perhaps not simpler, non-commutative Lie group, the affine group $ax+b$. The exponential is still a bijection, so it gives an $\mathbb R$-group, but the exponential does not preserve rational elements. It contains $\mathbb Q$-monoids, but they are more complicated.